# C# - Multiple models in a single view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a web app using Visual Studio 2017, Entity Framework Core. I want to combine 2 models into one view. I have 2 classes - Company & Employee that I want to combine. I want the employee info to be displayed alongside company info. What's the most elegant approach? I'm struggling quite a bit since this is my first web app.

Here's my base code:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Company.Model
{
    public class Company
    {
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyWebsite { get; set; }
        public string CompanyPresident { get; set; }

    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CompanyApp.Data;
using CompanyApp.Model;

namespace CompanyApp.Controllers
{
    public class CompanyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CompanyContext _context;

        public CompanyController(ManagementContext context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }

        // GET: Companies
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Companies.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Company/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var company = await _context.Companies
                .Include(s => s.CompanyEmployee)
                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Employee)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CompanyID == id);
            if (company == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(company);
        }

        // GET: Company/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Company/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CompanyID,CompanyWebsite,CompanyPresident")] Company company)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(company);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(company);
        }

        // GET: Company/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var company = await _context.Companies.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CompanyID == id);
            if (company == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(company);
        }

        // POST: Companies/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("CompanyID,CompanyWebsite,CompanyPresident")] Company company)
        {
            if (id != company.CompanyID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(company);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!CompanyExists(company.CompanyID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(company);
        }

        // GET: Company/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var company = await _context.Companies
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CompanyID == id);
            if (company == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(company);
        }

        // POST: Company/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var company = await _context.Companies.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CompanyID == id);
            _context.Companies.Remove(company);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        private bool CompanyExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Companies.Any(e => e.CompanyID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a view model containing the properties you want to display/edit in the view.

Comment: I suggest having a connection like inside the company model have a Employee property. Then you can just return an Icollection of all employees in that Company or return a single Employee based on its Id. Also your Company model doesn't contain CompanyEmployee or Employee so how can you add them in the Include, as I am sure Companies is your DbSet for Company.

Comment: There are 10 different ways you can do it. Look at this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1108855/ways-to-Bind-Multiple-Models-on-a-View-in-MVC

Answer (score 1):

You should create new a model that include all property you need. For example as below:

```
public class CompanyModel
    {
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyWebsite { get; set; }
        public string CompanyPresident { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }

var company = await _context.Companies
                .Include(s => s.CompanyEmployee)
                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Employee)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CompanyID == id);

//Bind data from company into CompanyModel
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example of these things can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) I would suggest in Company model to add

```
 public Company(){ Employee = new HashSet<Employee>(); }
 public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee (get;set);
```

and add to Employee

```
[ForeignKey("Company")]
public int CompanyId{get;set;}
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

As well as having to add your binding in the DBContext class not the controller

```
public class CompanyContext : DbContext { 
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees  { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
        {entity.HasOne(d => d.Company)
                .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId);
        });
    }
}
```

The code for the modelBuilder may need some changes, to work to your needs and models

Comment: Hi Edward, I'm using VS 2017 which doesn't support your code.

Comment: Please explain how it doesn't work. My code is based out of VS 2015 community and works for ASPNetCore. Add the visual studio 2017 tag to the question.